# Do you need to put the names of TV shows in quotation marks or not?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

Which of the following sentences is correct?

Version 1:

> There are TV shows like Dragon's Den and Shark Tank.

Version 2:

> There are TV shows like "Dragon's Den" and "Shark Tank".

Comment: This is just a matter of style. Either is OK, or you could italicize them: *Dragon's Den*.

Comment: Sometimes such names mess with interpretation of the sentence. In that case it's best to set them off somehow: bold, italic, quote *etc.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to distinguish titles of works is a matter of style. There is no single, universally correct answer; you should adhere to the guidance of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, your preferred [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579).

For example, the Chicago Manual of Style stipulates that the [titles of television shows](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch08/ch08_sec185.html) should be italicized, but that individual episode names should be demarcated with quotation marks. APA style [dictates the same](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/how-to-capitalize-and-format-reference-titles-in-apa-style.html).

Associated Press style, on the other hand, prefers that the names of television shows should be wrapped in quotation marks, and [not italicized or underlined](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/735/02/).

Bluebook legal citation, for yet another example, wants the name of the show and episode together, separated by a colon, and [both italicized](http://libguides.law.wfu.edu/content.php?pid=230403&sid=1999196), without quotation marks. Journal names and film titles, incidentally, are to be cited neither with italics nor with quotation marks, but with small caps.

Comment: See tchrist's meta rants about small caps not being included on SE. (He does have a point)